# Mute audio streams selectively

Tags: ffmpeg

I have this command

```
ffmpeg -y -i a.MOV -itsoffset 00:00:2.061 -i b.MP4 -itsoffset 00:00:4.016 -i c.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:8.016 -i d.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=4016[a1];..." -map [a1] -map [v] -r 60 -vcodec h264 zusammen.mp4
```

It should mute everything but [a1], but it doesn't. How do I mute everything but [a1]?

Full command for reference:

```
ffmpeg -y -i a.MOV -itsoffset 00:00:2.061 -i b.MP4 -itsoffset 00:00:4.016 -i c.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:8.016 -i d.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=4016[a1];color=000000:s=1920x1080[hg];[0:v]scale=505:284[ru1];[2:v]scale=505:284[lu1];[3:v]scale=505:284[lu2];[hg][1:v]overlay[a];[a][ru1]overlay=x=1343:y=723[b];[b][lu1]overlay=x=72:y=723[c];[c][lu2]overlay=x=72:y=723[aus_v]" -map [a1] -map [aus_v] -r 60 -vcodec h264 zusammen.mp4
```

Comment: What's the full command?

Comment: @Gyan Updated. What are your ideas?

Comment: So, only a1 should be heard in entire video?

Comment: @Gyan a1. What are your ideas now?

Answer (score 0):

If you add itsoffset, don't add adelay. Use aresample instead to plug in initial gap.

`ffmpeg -y -i a.MOV -itsoffset 00:00:2.061 -i b.MP4 -itsoffset 00:00:4.016 -i c.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:8.016 -i d.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[a1];color=000000:s=1920x1080[hg];[0:v]scale=505:284[ru1];[2:v]scale=505:284[lu1];[3:v]scale=505:284[lu2];[hg][1:v]overlay[a];[a][ru1]overlay=x=1343:y=723[b];[b][lu1]overlay=x=72:y=723[c];[c][lu2]overlay=x=72:y=723[aus_v]" -map [a1] -map [aus_v] -r 60 -vcodec h264 zusammen.mp4`

Comment: What was your thought process? How did you get to this? Please elaborate. Also, why does the video output have 60fps as mentioned, but looks like 30fps? a.MOV is 30fps, but b.MP4 is 60fps.

Comment: `-r 60` will dupe or drop frames to achieve output rate. It does not retime frames. As for the audio, only a1 is mapped so that will be the only audio in the output.